# Beginner at sql, need aid with using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

This is the error I'm receiving: invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I program in

```
SELECT prod.LineNumber ,
    "Pounds Made" = SUM(prod.PoundsMade) ,
    "Down Time" = SUM(prodDown.DownTimeHrs + DownTimeMins / 60) ,
    prodDown.LineNumber ,
    availHrs.LineNumber ,
    "Available Hours" = SUM(availHrs.AvailableHRS)
FROM   rpt_Line_Shift_Prod AS prod
    INNER JOIN rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime AS prodDown
    INNER JOIN rpt_LINE_Shift_AvailableHrs AS availHrs ON prodDown.LineNumber = availHrs.LineNumber ON prodDown.LineNumber = prod.LineNumber
--ON availHrs.LineNumber = prod.LineNumber
GROUP BY prod.LineNumber
```

I'm using three tables here, all that I have renamed prodDown, prod, and availHrs.

THANK YOU!

Comment: You need to put the columns that are in your select list that are not being aggregated in your group by `availHrs.LineNumber`, `prod.LineNumber`, `prodDown.LineNumber`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  prod.LineNumber
      ,"Pounds Made" = SUM(prod.PoundsMade)
      ,"Down Time" = SUM(prodDown.DownTimeHrs + DownTimeMins/60)
      , prodDown.LineNumber
      , availHrs.LineNumber
      ,"Available Hours" = SUM(availHrs.AvailableHRS)     
FROM rpt_Line_Shift_Prod AS prod
INNER JOIN rpt_Line_Shift_ProdDownTime AS prodDown
    ON prodDown.LineNumber = prod.LineNumber
INNER JOIN rpt_LINE_Shift_AvailableHrs AS availHrs
    ON prodDown.LineNumber = availHrs.LineNumber
GROUP BY prod.LineNumber,prodDown.LineNumber, availHrs.LineNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Put ``` prodDown.LineNumber``and ```availHrs.LineNumber` into the GROUP BY clause as well:

```
GROUP BY prod.LineNumber,prodDown.LineNumber, availHrs.LineNumber
```

All columns in the select list that have no aggregation like `sum` need to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You group only by `prod.LineNumber`
while in your select you also have
`prodDown.LineNumber, availHrs.LineNumber` 
Add them in the group clause

```
GROUP by prod.LineNumber,prodDown.LineNumber, availHrs.LineNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `SUM()` or any other [aggregate function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) on a column, you need to make sure that any other columns in your select list are also grouped. This will make sure that you do not get any duplicates. So as the other answers suggest, you need to make sure that you include your other columns in your `GROUP BY` clause.